# Reverse Current leak Battery+Diode in parallel

Tags: batteries, current, diodes, leakage-current

on my design, I am using two coin batteries in parallel and each battery has a Schottky diode in series to block the reverse current, in theory, it will avoid the higher potential battery "charge" the lower potential battery.
[image]

But I am facing a higher current consumption when the two batteries are connected to the circuit, probably in reverse leak

**Single Battery** connected avg consumption 2.6uA

**Two Batteries** Connected Average Consumption 7.8uA

What should be the recommended to avoid that probable reverse current leak?

Change diodes, add a second diode in series (2 diodes per battery), replace diodes per an ideal diode IC?

#### update

diodes:MBR0520L
The voltage at uC e.g: 3V it takes higher voltage between the two Batteries, usually exist few 1-15mV in the difference between each battery

Comment: Is the supply voltage different when you use two batteries instead of just one? Please measure the actual voltage at the microcontroller. Also, please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the diodes you are using.

Comment: Schottky diodes typically have much higher reverse leakage current than normal diodes.  That low forward voltage drop and fast switching are nice, but come with that serious consequence.  Before placing 2 in series, I would first look into changing to a regular diode with better reverse characteristics.

Comment: Using two Batteries like the setup in the image above, the power consumption increases 3-6 times depending on the uC load, then this could be related purely to the reverse leakage?

Answer (score 3):

The reverse leakage current is not drawn into the datasheet diagrams for such low reverse voltages, but extrapolating the curve does indicate near 5uA of current could flow. For example a BAS40 would have 3 nanoamperes of reverse current at matching conditions so changing the schottky diode to a better might help.

Comment: I am able to replace to a BAS40 you are mentioning or some diode with lower reverse leakage current, what do you think about Ideal diodes IC?

Comment: There is no such thing as an ideal diode.
BAS40 is a good choice for you.
A silicon diode would have even lower leakage than BAS40, if you can accept the higher forward voltage drop.

Comment: Can reverse leakage current damage battery?